# org.Opencv.core.Mat cannot be Cast to java.util.list in android studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to calculate a histogram using opencv 2_4_9 to show in one of my activities but this error is keep popping up i have searched it everywhere i couldn't find any solution specifically to my problem if anyone could help me how to solve it..!!

```
     private void GetResult()
    {
        try
        {
//            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outPutFile.toString());
            image = new Mat(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(img, image);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

            List<Mat> hsv_planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
            //splitting into 3 planes r,g,b
            Core.split(image, hsv_planes);
            //the number of bins
            MatOfInt HistSize = new MatOfInt(256);
            //set the ranges for r,g,b
            final MatOfFloat HistRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);
            boolean accumulate = false;

            Mat h_hist = new Mat();
            Mat s_hist = new Mat();
            Mat v_hist = new Mat();
            //Compute the histograms using calcHist function
            Imgproc.calcHist((List<Mat>) hsv_planes.get(0), new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), h_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);
            Imgproc.calcHist((List<Mat>) hsv_planes.get(1), new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), s_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);
            Imgproc.calcHist((List<Mat>) hsv_planes.get(2), new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), v_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);

            int hist_w = 512;
            int hist_h = 600;
            long bin_w = Math.round((double) hist_w / 256);

            Mat HistImage = new Mat(hist_h, hist_w, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            //Normalization
            Core.normalize(h_hist, h_hist, 3, HistImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX);
            Core.normalize(s_hist, s_hist, 3, HistImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX);
            Core.normalize(v_hist, v_hist, 3, HistImage.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX);

            for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
                Point p1 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(h_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
                Point p2 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(h_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
                Core.line(HistImage, p1, p2, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);

                Point p3 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(s_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
                Point p4 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(s_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
                Core.line(HistImage, p3, p4, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);

                Point p5 = new Point(bin_w * (i - 1), hist_h - Math.round(v_hist.get(i - 1, 0)[0]));
                Point p6 = new Point(bin_w * (i), hist_h - Math.round(v_hist.get(i, 0)[0]));
                Core.line(HistImage, p1, p2, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);
            }
            Utils.matToBitmap(HistImage, photoo);
            img_histogram.setImageBitmap(photoo);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to cast a Mat to a List of Mat objects which isn't possible.
Initialize arrays for the different planes. For example:

```
        List<Mat> hList = new ArrayList<>();
        hList.add(hsv_planes.get(0));
        List<Mat> sList = new ArrayList<>();
        sList.add(hsv_planes.get(1));
        List<Mat> vList = new ArrayList<>();
        vList.add(hsv_planes.get(2));

        //Compute the histograms using calcHist function
        Imgproc.calcHist(hList, new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), h_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);
        Imgproc.calcHist(sList, new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), s_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);
        Imgproc.calcHist(vList, new MatOfInt(3), new Mat(), v_hist, HistSize, HistRange, accumulate);
```